# ClassCastException when using wildcard in java

Tags: java, classcastexception

I got `ClassCastException` when running java code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "{" +
                "\"number\": 1" +
                "}";
        // method1
        Integer integer = get();
        String number1 = String.valueOf(integer);
        // method2
        String number2 = String.valueOf(get());
    }

    static <T> T get() {
        return (T) (new Integer(0));
    }
}
```

And the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class [C (java.lang.Integer and [C
> are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Why method2 does not work?

Comment: Your method `get()` is a blind cast hidden by generics. It’s calling the `char[]` ctor.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know which `valueOf()` overload you intend to call in the second example. It's trying `valueOf(char[])` and the cast is failing.

Comment: This is why `(T)` generates a compiler warning.

Comment: As to _why_ it's picking `valueOf(char[])` instead of one of the other overloads and not producing an ambiguous method call error - that would be interesting.  I'm sure this resolution is detailed in the JLS somewhere but I'm not good enough to be able to find it.  My guess is that it's picking the `valueOf(Object)` and `valueOf(some subclass of Object)` first (ignoring the primitives) and picking `valueOf(char[])` instead of `valueOf(Object)` because it is more specific.